# Get PHP array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

)
```

Now I want each array value into one single array. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want `array(1,2,3,3,4)` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// PHP >= 5.3:
function array_value_recursive($key, array $arr){
    $val = array();
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
        if($k == $key) array_push($val, $v);
    });
    return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively parse the array with a function:

```
$multiDimArr = array(...);

function getSingleArray( $multiDimArr ) {

   $singleArray = array();

   foreach($multiDimArr as $row) {
       if( is_array($row) ) {
           getSingleArray($row); // recursive call -> row it cand be also multi dimensional
       }
       else {
           $singleArray[] = $val;
       }
   }

   return $singleArray;
}
```

I really hope this will help!!